# Get JScrollPane to move based on current item?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I currently have a `JScrollpane` which has a list of buttons that run off the bottom of the container and cause the vertical scroll bar to appear (which is intended). At pre-defined intervals on a timer these buttons will become "selected". If one of the buttons selected is off the screen I would like to JScrollPane to automatically move itself so the selected button is fully visible on the screen.

I did a bit of looking on here and apparently the `scrollRectToVisible` method is what I am supposed to be using but it doesn't do anything for me.

I'm doing the following:

My `ScrollPane` contains a `JPanel` which is set to `BoxLayout` in the YAxis. I add a bunch of buttons to this panel. Once all the buttons are added a `Timer` starts to increment through these buttons and highlight them. After each increment in the timer I am calling the following line:

```
elevatorScroller.scrollRectToVisible(elevatorLevels[position].getBounds());
```

My intention here is to have the `JScrollPane` move the the currently highlighted button and continue to do so, however I'm not getting any movement.

`elevatorScroller` is my `JScrollPane` and the `elevatorLevels` array houses my buttons.

Any idea what might be causing this not to move? Do I have to call `repaint` or anything after advising the `JScrollPane` to move?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).  Incorporate a call to [`scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the documentation for the `scrollRectToVisible` method incorrectly which states:

> Forwards the scrollRectToVisible() message to the JComponent's parent

The keyword here is **parent** by calling the `scrollRectToVisible()` method directly to my `JScrollPane` nothing was happening as the parent of that item was a JFrame. By instead passing the `scrollRectToVisible()` method to my `JPanel` it passed on the above to its parent who was the `JScrollPane` and it now works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> "I currently have a JScrollpane which has a list of buttons that run off the bottom of the container and cause the vertical scroll bar to appear (which is intended). At pre-defined intervals on a timer these buttons will become "selected". If one of the buttons selected is off the screen I would like to JScrollPane to automatically move itself so the selected button is fully visible on the screen."

You could also use the `JViewPort` of the `JScrollPane` and use `setViewPosition(Point)` of the `JViewPort`. Something like this

```
public void setView(JScrollPane scroll, Component comp) {
    JViewport view = scroll.getViewport();
    Point p = comp.getLocation();
    view.setViewPosition(p);
}
```

Here's a running example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ChangeViewPort {
    Component activeComponent;
    Component[] buttons;
    int componentIndex = 0;

    public ChangeViewPort() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(boxLayout);
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            panel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
        }
        buttons = panel.getComponents();
        activeComponent = buttons[componentIndex];
        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);

        Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ((JButton)activeComponent).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                if (componentIndex >= buttons.length - 1) {
                    componentIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    componentIndex ++;
                }
                activeComponent = buttons[componentIndex];
                ((JButton)activeComponent).setForeground(Color.red);
                setView(scroll, activeComponent);
                System.out.println(((JButton)activeComponent).getActionCommand());
            }
        });
        timer.start();

        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setView(JScrollPane scroll, Component comp) {
        JViewport view = scroll.getViewport();
        Point p = comp.getLocation();
        view.setViewPosition(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new ChangeViewPort();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Scrolling a Form](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/scrolling-a-form/). It was designed to handle scrolling as a user tabs from component to component in a form. But the logic just looks for focus changes so it should also work when you have a Timer that changes focus to a different component.